# Difference between sheaf of parallel straight lines and the surface generated from the union of its lines

Tags: functions, geometry

I'm not a mathematician (and I'm not a native speaker either) so I apologize if some of the things I'm saying are inaccurate or incorrect.

I'll try to be as intuitive as possible. Suppose I have a sheaf of parallel straight lines. If I understood it correctly, the union of those generates a surface. However, there is a difference between the sheaf of lines themselves and the surface, right? For example, take a straight line that is conplanar to the ones of the sheaf mentioned above but has a different slope. This line would not belong to the sheaf but still "belong" to the surface generated by the union of the lines of the sheaf, am I right? I'd just like to know if what I've said so far makes sense.

Additionally, say I have a non-convex and continuous function F and I want to define the set of all the functions G obtained as the horizontal shifting of F in a given interval [a, b]. How can I do that? Does what I've said about the sheaf of straight lines also hold for the set of functions mentioned here (i.e. there is a difference between the set and the surface I can generate from the "union of the functions")?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by a "sheaf of lines"? The mathematical meaning of "sheaf" that I am most familiar with does appear to be what you are talking about.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. The set of all the straight lines with a given slope. An example would be y=x+k

Comment: The union of all straight lines with a given slope is *all* of space (whichever dimension of space you are working in). It is not a surface.

Comment: Okay, still, the set of those straight lines and the space would not be the same unless do the union, right?

Comment: Techniqually, no. The set of lines is a set of sets of points, while space is a set of points. However, in geometry, one tends to ignore such fine points of set theory.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you also help me with the second part of the question? Thank you again!!

Comment: Your "horizontal shifting" is normally called "horizontal translation". The set you are looking for appears to be $$\{G : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R\mid \exists c\in [a,b]. \forall x, G(x) = F(x + c)\}$$But I can't be sure because your description is ambiguous.